# Problem multiplying value in pandas dataframe to fixed number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am trying to multiply values in the column with a fixed integer but the result is the column value is repeated the amount of times of the fixed integer instead. The data sheet is imported from google sheets using this method. What i'm thinking is happening is that the value isn't seen as an integer so I need some help in changing it so the numerical values of my dataframe can be math'd.

```
osh = googlesh.open("project3").sheet1
data = osh.get_all_values()
headers = data.pop(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df['Days in month'] = 30
df['Ad set monthly budget'] = df['Ad set daily budget']* df['Days in month']

print(df)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxUMl.png)

Comment: Without access to the data, we cannot reproduce this. Could you at least show us the output of `df.dtypes`? I assume that at least one of them is not a numerical datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a datatype problem you can either use `pandas.Series.astype`:

```py
df['Ad set daily budget'] = df['Ad set daily budget'].astype('int')
```

Or `pandas.to_numeric`:

```py
df['Ad set daily budget'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Ad set daily budget'])
```

Comment: pandas.to_numeric works! Thank you! So I would have to do this for every column that I would like to math on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can cast it to a type int and check to see what the df column type is by df['Ad set daily budget'].types

```
  osh = googlesh.open("project3").sheet1
    data = osh.get_all_values()
    headers = data.pop(0)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    df['Days in month']= 30
    df['Ad set monthly budget'] = df['Ad set daily budget'].astype(int)* df['Days in month']
    
    print(df)
```

Comment: As Robby the Belgian said, check the types and see what they are with df.types